# C# How to only select strings based on a common set of characters?

Tags: c#

I have certain numbers placed in lines in a file, the only lines I am interested with are the lines that contain the set of characters "4 2 0" in this order example below:

.....

128 2 2 0 24 49 50 46

129 4 2 0 26 51 36 54 53

130 4 2 0 26 51 41 52 56

....

Here I would discard the line that starts by 128, and keep the two others. What is the best way to do this for the whole file(knowing that lines with such a set of characters are not necessarily at the same spot)? Thank you for your help...

Comment: What if 4 2 0 appears later in the string, like `128 2 2 0 24 4 2 0`  ?  Should this line be kept or discarded?

Comment: Normally it should be kept ,but in my specific case  this never happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
        string str = @"128 2 2 0 24 49 50 46

129 4 2 0 26 51 36 54 53

130 4 2 0 26 51 41 52 56";

        string[] strSplitted = str.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        List<string> result = strSplitted.ToList();

        foreach (var item in strSplitted)
        {
            if (!item.Contains("4 2 0"))
            {
                result.Remove(item);
            }
        }
```

The "result" variable will have the right results.